# Why does a+1 == *(a+1) in this example?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a[3][3] = {{22, 33, 44}, {55, 66, 77}, {88, 99, 100}};
    std::cout << a[1] << '\n' << a + 1 << '\n' << *(a + 1);
}
```

```
0x0013FF68
0x0013FF68
0x0013FF68
```

Why does `a+1 == *(a+1)`?

Comment: This might help: http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/arrayptr/23two-dim-array-memory-layout.html

Comment: @AndyG, `*(a+1)` is `a[1]`, not `a[1][0]`.

Answer (score 15):

`a + 1` is the address of the second element in `a` and could also be written as `&a[1]` (which is equivalent to `&*(a + 1)` by definition).

`*(a + 1)` is an lvalue referring to the second array. It's equivalent to `a[1]` by definition.
 
Just like with any other array to pointer decay, this lvalue decays to a pointer to the first element of the array it refers to, i.e. it decays to `&a[1][0]`. But that is equivalent to the address of that array object itself. So the value is the same as that of `&a[1]` ... which is precisely how we defined the value of the expression `a + 1` above.

Note that the array is decayed to a pointer because the best match for the second insertion is [`operator<<(void const*)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt). Consider

```
int (*p1)[3] = a + 1;

int (&p2)[3] = *(a + 1); // We could also have written *p1

int* p3 = p2; // The array-to-pointer decay

assert( static_cast<void*>(p1) == static_cast<void*>(p3) );
```